# Disable English "variations" on Firefox spellcheck

Tags: firefox, spell-check

I'm using Firefox 66.0.2 on Linux, and the language list on the spellchecker is a *bit* too big:

[image]

I want to have spellcheck only for "US", "UK" and "Brazil".

Here's what I've already tried:

- Disable every dictionary on about:addons
- Disable every language pack on about:addons

Spellcheck is still active. Huh?